# angularjs how to change tempate url dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in my module. And I want to change the `templateUrl` based on a attribute.

HTML

```
    <div test stage="dynamicstage"></div>
```

Module

```
angular.module('trial', [])
    .controller('trialCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dynamicstage = 'Welcome';
    })
    .directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'stage': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('stage', function(condition){
                if(stage === 'welcome'){
                   templateUrl: "hello.html";
                }else{
                    different template url...
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This does not work. The `templateurl` is not loaded into the div. I want to change the templateUrl dynamically is this possible.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Look at this post: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very transparent in Angular. `templateUrl` can be a function to dynamically construct template URL, however in your case you need a scope, which is not yet available at the moment URL is constructed.

You can do something like this with the help of `ngInclude`:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'stage': '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('stage', function(condition) {
                if (scope.stage === 'Welcome') {
                    scope.templateUrl = "hello.html";
                } else {
                    scope.templateUrl = "other.html";
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/l1IysXubJvMPTIphqPvn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1 :**

```
scope.$watch('stage', function(condition){
    var templateUrl;
    if(stage === 'welcome'){
        templateUrl = "hello.html";
    } else{
        templateUrl = "someothertemplate.html";
    };

    //load the template;
    $http.get(templateUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            // template is loaded.
            // add it and compile it.
            angular.element(element).html(response.data);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
});
```

**Solution2:** 
Use ng-include

```
<div test stage="dynamicstage">
    <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
</div>
```

Inside directive:

```
scope.$watch('stage', function(condition){
    var templateUrl;
    if(stage === 'welcome'){
        templateUrl = "hello.html";
    } else{
        templateUrl = "someothertemplate.html";
    };

    scope.$parent.templateUrl = templateUrl; // make sure that templateUrl is updated in proper scope
})
```